# Crash while executing fetch request

Tags: iphone, core-data, asynchronous, crash, request

I had a crash while executing executeFetchRequest:error:

`MyApp[595]` has active assertions beyond permitted time:

```
{(
    <SBProcessAssertion: 0x1e5d1260> identifier: Suspending process: MyApp[595] 
permittedBackgroundDuration: 10.000000 reason: suspend owner pid:29 preventSuspend
  preventThrottleDownCPU  preventThrottleDownUI
```

And this is my code:

```
NSString *predString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"categoryId MATCHES '%@'", categoryId];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predString];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray* objects = [context executeFetchRequest: request error: &error];
```

As far as I understand, the fetch, done synchronously in the main thread, took too much time, more than 10 secs, and the process was suspended.

Browsing in internet I found this nice solution to make the fetch async:

http://blog.zssz.me/2010/01/asynchronous-fetch-in-core-data.html

But i am wondering if actually my assumption is correct, and if there are simpler solutions to this problem.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the `MATCHES` operator with an SQL store (which you are almost certainly using) because sqlite does not support regex.  I would have expected it to error out instead of timing out but apparently not.

You want to use `CONTAINS` or even better, `==`. If you have an attribute called `catergoryID` it usually denotes an attribute with a specific unique value and not one that has a lot of minor variations. Using `==`/`equals` will produce a vastly faster fetch.

Comment: Thanks TechZen. The rest of the cases don't error out, but return uncorrect results. I will change it. Do you think that fetching in background is necessary anyways?

Comment: It usually isn't necessary except for very large data sets. Besides, if you are fetching information to display to the user via the UI, do you want the user to keep working on the out of date information? You probably don't so fetching in the background for the UI usually serves no purpose. However, the real answer is always the same: start with the simplest solution and stress test it. Only employ a more complicated solution is the simplest solution is tested and proven inadequate.

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear :)

I'd try it in a background thread and see what happens.